# Golangでinterface(のパラメータ)をコピーしたい。

Tags: go

Go言語で引数として渡されたinterafaceをコピーしてスライスに格納したいです。

つまり下記にようなことがしたいです。

```
func f(x AInterface){
    s := make([]AInterface, 10)
    for i := 0; i< 10; i++{
        s[i] = x
    }
}
```

これだとそれぞれの要素が1つの構造体への参照を持つことになると思います。それぞれ独立した構造体を指すインタフェースを持つスライスを作成するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 構造体のスライス(x:interface{} 型)を渡すとそのコピー(s)を返す関数という事でしょうか？ https://play.golang.org/p/s9v2mKiN4m

Comment: 遅くなってすみません。スライスではなくインタフェースを実装した構造体を渡すとそのコピーのスライスを返す関数です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あーやっとどうしたいのか見えてきました。
用途やなぜそうしたいのかを書かれていると
伝わりやすいと思います。

実用性皆無ですが、これっぽい感じになるかと思います。

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Object struct {
    x   int
    y   int
    arr []int
}

func main() {
    s := f(&Object{x: 1, y: 3, arr: []int{1, 2, 3}})

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("s[%d] = %p\n", i, s[i])
    }
}

func f(x interface{}) []interface{} {
    s := make([]interface{}, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        d := new(Object)
        *d = *(x.(*Object))
        s[i] = d
    }
    return s
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/j1iQVQPyD5

実用的にするにはファクトリパターンをご利用ください。